# Run Emacs within Bash

Tags: terminal, bash, emacs

I am looking for a way in Bash to run something within Emacs. For example, if you run emacs, press <kbd>esc</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> then type "life," you get a little simulation of Conway's Game of Life. How could this be done via Bash?

Don't have much so far:

```
#!/bin/sh
emacs
```

I've read about using `^]` and such but doing

```
#!/bin/sh
emacs
^]
```

does not work (neither does `^[`)

Basically, how can I simulate all of these key presses in Bash, with the default Mac Emacs (22.1.1)?

Comment: I bet there is a command line argument you could pass to emacs to get it to fire up the life simulation. Is that basically what you want - to go directly from bash to the life simulation with no additional key presses?

Comment: @bmike Exactly.

Answer (score 1):

Use `emacs -f <function>`

E.g.: `emacs -f life` in this case.

[GNU Emacs Manual](http://www.cs.utah.edu/dept/old/texinfo/emacs19/emacs_37.html)